# How to break down an FX option P&L?

Tags: options

I am comparing the mark-to-market (MtM) valuations of two risk systems, with respect to FX Options.

My question is can I quantify the difference in MtM given the following:

**System1**

AUD/JPY, MTM = USD 461,000, Implied Vol. = 11.88%, Vega = USD 82,000, Forward Rate = 97.29 and USD Delta = -15,300,000

**System2**

AUD/JPY, MTM = USD 406,000, Implied Vol. = 12.14%, Vega = USD 77,000, Forward Rate = 97.81 and USD Delta = -13,600,000

Assuming both systems use Black Scholes, how can I quantify the difference in MtM (in USD) which is USD 55,000 by attributing it to:

- Difference in Implied Volatility and;
- Difference in Forward Rates?

I tried doing this and am still left with a small difference - is it possible to quantify that too?

Comment: It would be very helpful that formulas for forward rate, option price, vega, and delta are provided. Note that, for FX options, in particular, for values and hedge ratios in a currency not directly involved with the exchange rate (e.g., value in USD with option underlying exchange rate AUD/JPY), can be very tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Some residual difference is expected due to gamma and other higher order greeks, and to rate assumptions as mentioned above.  Also you should make sure about the meaning of delta expressed in USD for an AUD/JPY option; I am not sure that is standard across systems.  It could be the dollar value of the JPY to hold as hedge taking AUD as the riskless currency, or dollar value of AUD to hold as hedge taking JPY as riskless currency, or either the value of AUD or JPY to hold for a combined hedge of both currencies' moves against USD.  It could also be premium-included or forward versions of these.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that you use the same interest rate for AUD and JPY in both systems? The difference is quite large. The used model should be Garman–Kohlhagen which is Black Scholes with two interest rates. In which currency is the vega?